# Почему не завершается работа программы при await в Main?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, асинхронность, tpl

Смотрел что пишут про выполнение await, понял примерно следующее:

- если таск завершен, то просто продолжаем исполнение тут же (синхронно)
- если таск не завешен, то выходим из метода (что происходит дальше с основным потоком - под вопросом). Операция завернутая в таск можежет быть связанна с IO или CPU. В случае IO задача "спит" до волшебного сигнала от куда-то что пора искать поток на исполнение, с учетом контекста синхронизации. В случае CPU задача не "спит", а сразу начинает исполнение в потоке, выбор которого тоже зависит от контекста синхронизации.

Вроде все понятно, пока не посмотреть на Main. Тоже выходим из Main? Куда? Что мешает завершению программы в этот момент? Будет ли иметь занчение это CPU или IO задача или дополнительная конфигурация?

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = SomeLongAsync(hours: 10);
        await task;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
```

**Update**

добавляю визуализацию в дополнение к основному вопросу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не "выходим из метода", а "планируем продолжение" в точке с await. В случае с Main и Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); и окончание программы тоже входят в это "планируем продолжение".

Comment: vitidev, в том варианте который рассматриваем после "планируем продолжение" идет "выходим из метода" ?

Comment: Все ждут окончания Task-ов. Рантайм ждет окончания Task, который возвращает Main. А этот Task вернет [state-машина](https://habr.com/ru/post/260217/) (структура, в которую компилятор перепишет метод видя async). Когда обработаются все await и в очередном продолжении дойдет выполнение до конца метода Main, то эта скрытая стейт-машина пометит Task (от Main) завершенным. Рантайм увидит это и завершит процесс. А так - при вызове метода код сразу выполняется до явного выхода из метода или до точки "дальше выполнять нельзя, давай запланируем продолжить тут потом" (await)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Асинхронный мейн неявно обернут в синхронный. Операционная система не знает ничего об асинхронных делах в C#, для нее не бывает асинхронных мейнов.

Там что-то типа этого снаружи.

```
static void Main() // <-- точка входа здесь
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm sync Main");
    Main(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Exit sync Main");
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm async Main");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Exit async Main");
}
```

Это можно запустить и оно работает.

```
I'm sync Main
I'm async Main
Exit async Main
Exit sync Main
```

Что касается CPU/IO дел, то почитайте это: [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)

Если кратко, то `Task` никогда ничего не выполняет, он не может выполнять ничего и не умеет. Он умеет только ждать. Методы типа `Task.Run` используют потоки для запуска делегата, а в `Task` прикручивают колбэк выхода из потока, только и всего. Сам `Task` - это просто ожидалка, и совершенно не важно чего именно.

Если интересно, что такое CPU-Bound операция, и что делает `Task.Run`, то вот что

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Hello");
    string text = await RunAsync(GetHello);
    // то же самое можно записать так
    // string text = await RunAsync(() => GetHello());
    // или так
    // string text = await RunAsync(() => { return GetHello(); });
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {text}");
}

static Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => {
        (var t, var f) = ((TaskCompletionSource<T>, Func<T>))obj;
        try
        {
            T result = f();
            t.SetResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            t.SetException(ex);
        }
    }, (tcs, func));
    return tcs.Task;
}

static string GetHello()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return "Hello";
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Waiting for Hello
Result: Hello
```

Обратите внимание, всю работу здесь выполняет пул потоков, а не `Task`.

Comment: Вопрос в догонку. Из доки: "When the await operator suspends the enclosing async method, the control returns to the caller of the method.". Представляю это так что поток который был до await выйдет на вызывающий метод. Но исходя из ответа поток застрянет на Main(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).Wait(); (синхронная блокировка). Раньше думал что происходиты высвобождение этого потока в пул, а теперь запутался. И еще. Значит ли это что операция из таски и продолжения не могут в таком случае быть исполнены на вызыващем потоке (ситуацию когда таск выполнен еще до await не рассматриваем)?

Comment: @John распутывайтесь, представьте, что у вас обычный метод, возвращающий `Task`, забудьте про асинхронность, так вот, этот `Task` формируется и возвращается при первом вызове вами `await`. Никаких потоков не задействуется при этом, `Task` формируется синхронно. За работу `await` отвечает [машина состояний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1315925/373567). Когда `await` заканчивается, происходит повторный вызов метода, но уже в другом состоянии, то есть с того места, где `await` закончился, это называется "продолжение". Тема не простая, со временем разберетесь.

Comment: @John и никто нигде не застревает, просто когда вы вызываете метод, процессор идет выполнять код в нем, и не продолжит выполнять вызывающий метод, пока вызванный не выполнится полностью и не произойдет возврат `return`. `Wait()` - это по сути отправить процессор потупить внутрь `Task` до тех пор, пока `Task` на завершится, в рамках текущего потока, само собой.

Comment: @John представьте, вы `едете_на_машине()`, но потом вы остановились `поменять_колесо()`, машина не застряла, она просто не может ехать без вас. Когда замена колеса завершится и вы вернетесь за руль, то поедете дальше. А асинхронно, едете вы с женой домой, вы остановились у супермаркета, высадили жену `var жена_в_магазине = купить_продукты_async()` и поехали на заправку дальше `заправиться()`, вернулись к супермаркету, подождали жену `await жена_в_магазине` и поехали дальше. Это значит, что покупки выполнялись асинхронно, если будет угодно, то в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @John но "жена" это может быть вообще отдельный сервер, и вы обращаетесь к нему по сети, то есть тот самый поток вообще не на вашем процессоре может выполняться. В этом и есть смысл асинхронности, вы просто ждете, а работа может выполняться где угодно. И последнее: движок потоков, на котором едет `await` называется "контекст синхронизации" `SynchronizationContext`. Когда-нибудь вы сможете свой контекст написать, это не сложно.

Comment: Вот что возмутило в начале http://prntscr.com/26wjahh, но понял что в этой модели иногда не можем обойтись без синхронного ожидания основного потока. Хотя в доке нет подробностей что происходит с потоком на .Wait() (может spinwait, а может и нет).  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-wait

Comment: @John как что? Он просто передает методу Wait управление, как любому другому синхронному методу, а тот садится на WaitHandle в блокировку.